# Marshaling vectors of pointers

Tags: haskell, ffi

I'm trying to represent a Haskell [vector](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-0.11.0.0/docs/Data-Vector-Storable.html) of arbitrarily right-nested pairs (i.e. `Vector (Int64, (Int64, (...)))`) as a 2-d array in C (i.e. `int64_t**`), indexed first as the vector component, then the tuple component.

Here's my C function:

```
void test(int64_t** y, int32_t vecSize int16_t tupSize, int64_t* tup)
{
    printf("Tup vals: ");
    for(int i = 0; i < tupSize; i++) {
        printf("%" PRId64 ",",tup[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");


    printf("vec\n");
    for(int i = 0; i < vecSize; i++) {
        printf("%d: (", i);
        for(int j = 0; j < tupSize; j++) {
            printf("%" PRId64 ",", y[i][j]);
        }
        printf(")\n");
    }
}
```

On the Haskell side I have:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

import Data.Int
import Data.Vector.Storable (Vector, singleton, unsafeWith)

import Foreign.Marshal.Utils (with)
import Foreign.Ptr
import Foreign.Storable (Storable (..))

foreign import ccall unsafe "test" test :: Ptr (Ptr Int64) -> Int64 -> Int16 -> Ptr Int64 -> IO ()

-- instance assumes right-nested pairs, but not enforced at type level
instance (Storable a, Storable b)
  => Storable (a,b) where
  sizeOf _ = (sizeOf (undefined :: a)) + (sizeOf (undefined :: b))
  alignment _ = max (alignment (undefined :: a)) (alignment (undefined :: b))
  peek p = do
    a <- peek (castPtr p :: Ptr a)
    b <- peek (castPtr (plusPtr p (sizeOf a)) :: Ptr b)
    return (a,b)
  poke p (a,b) = do
    poke (castPtr p :: Ptr a) a
    poke (castPtr (plusPtr p (sizeOf a)) :: Ptr b) b

main :: IO ()
main = do
  let tup = (10,11) :: (Int64, Int64)
      vec = singleton (2,3) :: Vector (Int64, Int64)
  with tup $ \tptr -> 
    unsafeWith vec $ \vptr ->
      test (castPtr vptr) 1 2 (castPtr tptr)
```

This prints

```
Moduli: 10,11,
vec
Segmentation fault
```

which leads me to think that my `Storable (a,b)` instance is fine: I'm getting a pointer for `(Int64,Int64)`, then casting it to `Ptr Int64`, and reading the data just fine in C. So the question is what is going wrong with the vector? I'm attempting to do the same thing: create a `Vector (Int64, Int64)`, get a pointer of type `Ptr (Int64, Int64)` for it, and cast it to a `Ptr (Ptr Int64)`. Why am I getting a segfault when I try to access the array in C, and what is the proper way to marshal this data?

Comment: Recall that in C, an array of ints can decay into a pointer to int, and that an array of arrays of ints can decay into a pointer to array of ints, but _not_ to a pointer to pointer to int. You can't pass a `int a[3][5]` where a `int **a` is expected, but you can where a `int (*a)[5]` is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not using the same data format on the two sides. Your Haskell code produces a flat array of all the values in all the tuples of the vector, while your C code expects an array of *pointers*, one for each element of the vector, pointing to the values in that tuple.

If you could declare your C function like this (maybe this is valid C nowadays, I don't know)

```
void test(int64_t (*y)[tupSize], int32_t vecSize, int16_t tupSize, int64_t *tup)
```

then C would be using the same layout as Haskell. Otherwise, you can index manually with

```
//  SINGLE pointer |
//                 v
void test(int64_t *y, int32_t vecSize, int16_t tupSize, int64_t *tup)
...
    printf("%" PRId64 ",", y[i*tupSize+j]);
```

Comment: Unfortunately the point-of-array syntax doesn't compile for me, but the manual indexing works great.